# Why does the buffering of std::ifstream "break" std::getline when using LLVM?

Tags: c++, macos, pipe, clang, named-pipes

I have a simple C++ application which is supposed to read lines from a POSIX named pipe:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>

int main() {
    std::ifstream pipe;
    pipe.open("in");

    std::string line;
    while (true) {
        std::getline(pipe, line);
        if (pipe.eof()) {
            break;
        }
        std::cout << line << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Steps:

- I create a named pipe: `mkfifo in`.
- I compile & run the C++ code using `g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp && ./a.out`.
- I feed data to the `in` pipe:

```
sleep infinity > in &  # keep pipe open, avoid EOF
echo hey > in
echo cats > in
echo foo > in
kill %1                # this closes the pipe, C++ app stops on EOF
```

When doing this under Linux, the application successfully displays output after each `echo` command as expected (g++ 8.2.1).

When trying this whole process on macOS, output is only displayed after closing the pipe (i.e. after `kill %1`).
I started suspecting some sort of buffering issue, so i've tried disabling it like so:

```
std::ifstream pipe;
pipe.rdbuf()->pubsetbuf(0, 0);
pipe.open("out");
```

With this change, the application outputs nothing after the first `echo`, then prints out the first message after the second `echo` ("hey"), and keeps doing so, alwasy lagging a message behind and displaying the message of the previous `echo` instead of the one executed.
The last message is only displayed after closing the pipe.

I found out that on macOS `g++` is basically `clang++`, as 
`g++ --version` yields: "Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)".
After installing the real g++ using Homebrew, the example program works, just like it did on Linux.

I am building a simple IPC library built on named pipes for various reasons, so this working correctly is pretty much a requirement for me at this point.

<s>What is causing this weird behaviour when using LLVM?</s> (update: this is caused by libc++)

Is this a bug?

Is the way this works on g++ guaranteed by the C++ standard in some way?

How could I make this code snippet work properly using `clang++`?

**Update:**

This seems to be caused by the libc++ implementation of `getline()`.
Related links:

- [Why does libc++ getline block when reading from pipe, but libstdc++ getline does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47192984/why-does-libc-getline-block-when-reading-from-pipe-but-libstdc-getline-does)
- https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=23078

The questions still stand though.

Comment: The language standard says nothing about the timing of any output.  (It probably *should* say a little bit, but not about this multiprocess case.)  POSIX does, though, and this does look wrong—what happens if you use DOS newlines (`echo $'foo\r' >in`)?

Comment: @DavisHerring Yeah, you are right, I probably should have composed my words more precisely. Of course what I've meant is `std::getlines()` not blocking if the stream has a newline available. Trying it with DOS newlines yielded the same results.

Comment: Oddly, I see the desired behavior with an older “Apple LLVM version 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)” with a `_LIBCPP_VERSION` of 1101.

Comment: In the linked bug report I've found this response:

"The problem is actually in basic_filebuf<_CharT, _Traits>::underflow(). Around line 595, it calls fread to fill the filebuf's buffer. (by default, 4096 bytes). this read hangs until it can read an entire buffer-full. When it is talking to a file, and the file doesn't have that much data, it gets a short read. When it is talking to a pipe, it just waits until that much data is available."

This seems to suggest that this indeed is a bug. When I have time I should probably check the referred code in the two versions that we have tried.

Comment: Meanwhile I've started using an implementation based on POSIX getline() to get my code working on libc++ and libstdc++ as well, which is suboptimal as I have to mix C and C++ APIs, but it works at least.

Comment: If you want to make an IPC mechanism, I'd recommend something like UNIX domain sockets on boost ASIO (https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/posix/local.html).  Reading a "line" at a time using iostreams isn't very flexible or scalable...

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion, as it is a good one. In fact I have worked with boost's asyncio before, and yes, it would be an elegant solution for general IPC. However, the question is not "how to build a scalable&flexible IPC solution". As with most projects, I have requirements out of my reach to work with. The question is explicitly about the weird behaviour of `std::getline()` in libc++, not my reasons for reading from named pipes until a delimiter.

Comment: @krispetkrispet What questions still stand ? you seem to have concluded yourself it's a bug (I think you are correct) - Im not sure it is guarenteed (by who anyway - this is relying on external behavior as well), but it sure is implied if you read the introductions, etc.. How to make it work ? Just work around the bug. I think you can do that yourself - perhaps post the solution here if it's a neat one :)

Comment: @darune It's just weird that the bug report hasn't been touched since 2015, and I was wondering whether the C++ standard says anything regarding the behaviour of `fstream` on pipes. But sure, I've worked around the bug myself a few days after posting this, I'll post my solution so it may help others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have worked around this issue by wrapping POSIX `getline()` in a simple C API and simply calling that from C++.
The code is something like this:

```
typedef struct pipe_reader {
    FILE* stream;
    char* line_buf;
    size_t buf_size;
} pipe_reader;

pipe_reader new_reader(const char* pipe_path) {
    pipe_reader preader;
    preader.stream = fopen(pipe_path, "r");
    preader.line_buf = NULL;
    preader.buf_size = 0;
    return preader;
}

bool check_reader(const pipe_reader* preader) {
    if (!preader || preader->stream == NULL) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

const char* recv_msg(pipe_reader* preader) {
    if (!check_reader(preader)) {
        return NULL;
    }
    ssize_t read = getline(&preader->line_buf, &preader->buf_size, preader->stream);
    if (read > 0) {
        preader->line_buf[read - 1] = '\0';
        return preader->line_buf;
    }
    return NULL;
}

void close_reader(pipe_reader* preader) {
    if (!check_reader(preader)) {
        return;
    }
    fclose(preader->stream);
    preader->stream = NULL;
    if (preader->line_buf) {
        free(preader->line_buf);
        preader->line_buf = NULL;
    }
}
```

This works well against libc++ or libstdc++.

Answer (score 1):

As discussed separately, a `boost::asio` solution would be best, but your question is specifically about how `getline` is blocking, so I will talk to that.

The problem here is that `std::ifstream` is not really made for a FIFO file type.  In the case of `getline()`, it is trying to do a buffered read, so (in the initial case) it decides the buffer does not have enough data to reach the delimiter (`'\n'`), calls `underflow()` on the underlying `streambuf`, and that does a simple read for a buffer-length amount of data.  This works great for files because the file's length at a point in time is a knowable length, so it can return EOF if there's not enough data to fill the buffer, and if there is enough data, it simply returns with the filled buffer.  With a FIFO, however, running out of data does not necessarily mean `EOF`, so it doesn't return until the process that writes to it closes (this is your infinite `sleep` command that holds it open).

A more typical way to do this is for the writer to open and close the file as it reads and writes.  This is obviously a waste of effort when something more functional like `poll()`/`epoll()` is available, but I'm answering the question you're asking.