# Why is snprintf consistently 2x faster than ostringstream for printing a single number?

Tags: c++, performance, output

I was testing various approaches at formatting `double`s in C++, and here's some code I came up with:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <cstdio>
#include <random>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

inline long double currentTime()
{
    const auto now = std::chrono::steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch();
    return std::chrono::duration<long double>(now).count();
}

int main()
{
    std::mt19937 mt(std::random_device{}());
    std::normal_distribution<long double> dist(0, 1e280);
    static const auto rng=[&](){return dist(mt);};
    std::vector<double> numbers;
    for(int i=0;i<10000;++i)
        numbers.emplace_back(rng());

    const int precMax=200;
    const int precStep=10;

    char buf[10000];
    std::cout << "snprintf\n";
    for(int precision=10;precision<=precMax;precision+=precStep)
    {
        const auto t0=currentTime();
        for(const auto num : numbers)
            std::snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.*e", precision, num);
        const auto t1=currentTime();
        std::cout << "Precision " << precision << ": " << t1-t0 << " s\n";
    }

    std::cout << "ostringstream\n";
    for(int precision=10;precision<=precMax;precision+=precStep)
    {
        std::ostringstream ss;
        ss.precision(precision);
        ss << std::scientific;
        const auto t0=currentTime();
        for(const auto num : numbers)
        {
            ss.str("");
            ss << num;
        }
        const auto t1=currentTime();
        std::cout << "Precision " << precision << ": " << t1-t0 << " s\n";
    }
}
```

What makes me wonder is that at first, when precision is less than `40`, I get more or less the same performance. But then the difference goes to `2.1x` in favor of `snprintf`. See my output on Core i7-4765T, Linux 32-bit, g++ 5.5.0, libc 2.14.1, compiled with `-march=native -O3`:

```
snprintf
Precision 10: 0.0262963 s
Precision 20: 0.035437 s
Precision 30: 0.0468597 s
Precision 40: 0.0584917 s
Precision 50: 0.0699653 s
Precision 60: 0.081446 s
Precision 70: 0.0925062 s
Precision 80: 0.104068 s
Precision 90: 0.115419 s
Precision 100: 0.128886 s
Precision 110: 0.138073 s
Precision 120: 0.149591 s
Precision 130: 0.161005 s
Precision 140: 0.17254 s
Precision 150: 0.184622 s
Precision 160: 0.195268 s
Precision 170: 0.206673 s
Precision 180: 0.218756 s
Precision 190: 0.230428 s
Precision 200: 0.241654 s
ostringstream
Precision 10: 0.0269695 s
Precision 20: 0.0383902 s
Precision 30: 0.0497328 s
Precision 40: 0.12028 s
Precision 50: 0.143746 s
Precision 60: 0.167633 s
Precision 70: 0.190878 s
Precision 80: 0.214735 s
Precision 90: 0.238105 s
Precision 100: 0.261641 s
Precision 110: 0.285149 s
Precision 120: 0.309025 s
Precision 130: 0.332283 s
Precision 140: 0.355797 s
Precision 150: 0.379415 s
Precision 160: 0.403452 s
Precision 170: 0.427337 s
Precision 180: 0.450668 s
Precision 190: 0.474012 s
Precision 200: 0.498061 s
```

So my main question is: what is the reason for this twofold difference? And additionally, how can I make `ostringstream`'s performance closer to that of `snprintf`?

**NOTE**: another question, [Why is snprintf faster than ostringstream or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/445315/673852), is different from mine. First, there's no specific answer there, why formatting of a single number in different precisions is slower. Second, that question asks "why it's slower in general", which is too broad to be useful to answer my question, while this one asks about one specific scenario of formatting single `double` number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is snprintf faster than ostringstream or is it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/445315/why-is-snprintf-faster-than-ostringstream-or-is-it)

Comment: @Flopp it's not: first, there's no specific answer why formatting of a single number in different precisions is slower. Second, it asks "why it's slower in general", which is too handwavy to make any sense, while my question asks about one specific scenario.

Comment: I suspect you're building a DEBUG build.  When I build Release with Visual Studio, the perf numbers are only marginally different between snprintf and ostringstream.

Comment: @selbie see my remark about compilation options: `-march=native -O3`. It's definitely not debug mode.

Comment: @Ruslan: Then maybe GCC's `stringstream` implementation is crap. Or Visual Studio's `snprintf` implementation is crap.

Comment: C++ streams have been famous for being slow [Does the C++ standard mandate poor performance for iostreams, or am I just dealing with a poor implementation?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4340396/995714) [printf more than 5 times faster than std::cout?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12044357/995714), [C++ iostream vs. C stdio performance/overhead](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37894262/995714)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`std::ostringstream` calls `vsnprintf` twice: first time to try with a small buffer, and the second one with the correctly-sized buffer. See `locale_facets.tcc` around line 1011 (here `std::__convert_from_v` is a proxy for `vsnprintf`):

```
#if _GLIBCXX_USE_C99_STDIO
    // Precision is always used except for hexfloat format.
    const bool __use_prec =
      (__io.flags() & ios_base::floatfield) != ios_base::floatfield;

    // First try a buffer perhaps big enough (most probably sufficient
    // for non-ios_base::fixed outputs)
    int __cs_size = __max_digits * 3;
    char* __cs = static_cast<char*>(__builtin_alloca(__cs_size));
    if (__use_prec)
      __len = std::__convert_from_v(_S_get_c_locale(), __cs, __cs_size,
                    __fbuf, __prec, __v);
    else
      __len = std::__convert_from_v(_S_get_c_locale(), __cs, __cs_size,
                    __fbuf, __v);

    // If the buffer was not large enough, try again with the correct size.
    if (__len >= __cs_size)
      {
        __cs_size = __len + 1;
        __cs = static_cast<char*>(__builtin_alloca(__cs_size));
        if (__use_prec)
          __len = std::__convert_from_v(_S_get_c_locale(), __cs, __cs_size,
                        __fbuf, __prec, __v);
        else
          __len = std::__convert_from_v(_S_get_c_locale(), __cs, __cs_size,
                        __fbuf, __v);
      }
```

This exactly matches the observation that for small requested precision performance is the same as that of `snprintf`, while for larger precision it's 2x poorer.

Moreover, since the buffer used doesn't depend on any properties of `std::ostringstream` buffer, only on `__max_digits`, which is defined as `__gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits<_ValueT>::__digits10`, there doesn't seem to be any natural fix for this other than fixing `libstdc++` itself.

I've [reported](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=84666) it as bug to libstdc++.